# Quadratic Functions Word Problem Help

Tags: quadratics, word-problem

Two numbers differ by 18. determine the two numbers if the sum of their square is 3860.

Comment: Difference, think subtract. Sum, think add. Have you been able to setup the equations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

if two numbers differ by $18$ than they are $x+18$ and $x$, so write that the sum of their squares is $3860$ and you have a second degree equation...

Comment: ok now i understand where i went wrong!